# How to show push notification at notification area iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `Json` `Array` Push `Notification` Arriving Like This,

```
 {
    "alert" : "You got your emails.",

    "badge" : 9
 }
```

I want to instantly display this array in notification tray of iphone | ipad

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, This Looks Good But I Want to Arrive Notification in this area PFA http://imgur.com/Az2smpL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use below Library to show notification in Navigation Bar

[MPNotificationView](https://github.com/ekurutepe/MPNotificationView)

An in-app notification view that mimics the iOS 6 notification views which appear above the status bar.

**Features:**

> Animation and layout similar to iOS 6 notifications
>
> Provides two UILabels and an UIImageView
>
> Simple API
>
> Enqueues multiple notifications and shows them with a default
>      duration of 2 seconds.

[image]

## And if You want to get Notification, YOu have to do few code in Appdelegate.m File As given Below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
{
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

}

#pragma mark Notification tokan

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    deviceTokenForPushNotification  = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceTokenForPushNotification = [deviceTokenForPushNotification stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];


    NSUserDefaults *objUserDefalut = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [objUserDefalut setValue:deviceTokenForPushNotification forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    [objUserDefalut synchronize];

    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{

    NSUserDefaults *objUserDefalut = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [objUserDefalut setValue:@"" forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    [objUserDefalut synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, This Looks Good But I Want to Arrive Notification in this area   PFA  http://imgur.com/Az2smpL

Comment: Fot that you have to Create Apple push notification Certficate(APNS).
After that , you get .PEM/.P12 File, which is needed for Push Certificate in Server Side.

Answer (score 1):

In your `AppDelegate` File.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSString *msg = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]objectForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"MyTitle" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

This will show your message in your payload. Providing your application is in `background`,or `foreground`, `NOT terminated`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, This Looks Good But I Want to Arrive Notification in this area PFA http://imgur.com/Az2smpL

Comment: That is managed by iOS and the string you provice as the key "alert" inside the payload, will be automatically shown by ios. Unless you are trying to perform User Interactive notifications you cannot customise that notification.